# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

Why this code doesn't work?

```
const whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000' , 'https://localhost:3443', 'http://localhost:4200','http://localhost:5000'];

const corsOptionsDelegate  =(req: Request, callback: any) => {
    let corsOptions;
    console.log('origin' + req.header('Origin'));
    if(req.header('Origin') != null){
        if(whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1){
            console.log("index : " + whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')));
            corsOptions = { origin : true};
        }
        else{
            console.log('here else :' + whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')));
            corsOptions = { origin : false };
        }
    }

    callback(null , corsOptions);
};
```

ERROR:

> Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'string'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'string'.

Error comes from `(req.header('Origin'))` parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatically-detected type for `whitelist` is `string[]` since you initialized it only with strings as elements.

The `indexOf` method for a `string[]` array then accordingly gets the signature `indexOf(searchElement: string, fromIndex?: number | undefined): number` - note that `searchElement` is a `string`.

`req.header` can return `undefined` if the requested header does not exist, hence the type of its return value is `string | undefined` and not just `string`.

Therefore, by writing `whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin'))` you are attempting to pass a `string | undefined` to something that expects a `string`.

You can solve this by first checking whether the header exists and only then test whether it's whitelisted (also, I'm going to use `includes` here instead of `indexOf` because you don't seem to use the actual index anyway other than in your debug log):

```js
const origin = req.header('Origin')
if (origin !== undefined && whitelist.includes(origin) {
  corsOptions = { origin: true }
} else {
  corsOptions = { origin: false }
}
```

...which could be further simplified to this:

```js
const origin = req.header('Origin')
corsOptions = { origin: origin !== undefined && whitelist.includes(origin) }
```

You could also use a default value for a missing origin header, say, an empty string, and then the code becomes even simpler:

```js
corsOptions = { origin: whitelist.includes(req.header('Origin') ?? '') }
```